# A static Tic-Tac-Toe board with Gui3 in python

Tags: python

OK, so my task is to create a window that displays a Tic Tac Toe board with one X and one O. This is being done in Gui3, which my online instructor has so sweetly not instructed us much on. Anyways, below i have my current code. I am able to create the window and the canvas, but i have not mastered how to actually get the 4 lines, 2 vertical and 2 horizontal, to print. Or the X and O. I need some tips on how to get the grid with a 25 pixel boarder!

```
# make the Gui3 module available
import Gui3


# setup some global constants
CANVAS_WIDTH = 350
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 350

# the main function
def main():

  # create a window and give it a title
  win = Gui3.Gui()
  win.title("Tic tac toe")

  # create a canvas to draw in
  canvas =(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)



main()
```

Comment: What have you tried to draw those lines and icons? Better ask specific questions than requesting other to code for you.

Comment: Is this some custom module provided by your instructor? I can't seem to find any Python module names Gui3. In any case, do you have a link to documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try looking through the on-line class notes for this week.  "The Gui Module" gives you all the necessary information to draw shapes and lines for this week's assignment.  Just remember how to work with Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I did! i'm curious who you are?